# Remove a group from data frame if all values across are a certain number?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame where I'd like to remove entire groups if their y value is the same across 6 time points.

| Patients | Time | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 |
| 1 | b | 5 |
| 1 | c | 5 |
| 1 | d | 5 |
| 1 | e | 5 |
| 1 | f | 5 |
| 2 | a | 4 |
| 2 | b | 4 |
| 2 | c | 5 |
| 2 | d | 5 |
| 2 | e | 5 |
| 2 | f | 5 |

Basically, I'd like to remove all patients from this data frame who have a status of "5" at ALL time points. If a patient has any value apart from 5 at any point in time I'd like to include them.

I tried

```
df <- df %>%

filter(a !=5 & b !=5 & c !=5 & d !=5 & e !=5 & f !=5)
```

To no avail, unfortunately. Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any`/`all` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Patients) %>% filter(any(Status != 5))
#With `all`
#df %>% group_by(Patients) %>% filter(!all(Status == 5))

#  Patients Time  Status
#     <int> <chr>  <int>
#1        2 a          4
#2        2 b          4
#3        2 c          5
#4        2 d          5
#5        2 e          5
#6        2 f          5
```

This can be also be written with base R :

```
subset(df, ave(Status != 5, Patients, FUN = any))

#and `data.table` : 
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(Status != 5)], Patients]
```

---

Without grouping by `Patients` you can do :

```
subset(df, Patients %in% unique(Patients[Status != 5]))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Patients = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), Time = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f"), Status = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(
  patients = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6)),
  time = rep(letters[1:6],2),
  status = c(rep(5,6),rep(4,2),rep(5,4))
)

df %>% 
  group_by(patients) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(status*6 != sum(status))
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your problem correctly one of these two solutions should help:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# your test data
df <- data.table::fread("Patients   Time    Status
1   a   5
1   b   5
1   c   5
1   d   5
1   e   5
1   f   5
2   a   4
2   b   4
2   c   5
2   d   5
2   e   5
2   f   5")

# one option to get all rows diferent than 5
df %>% 
  # exclude everything where Status is 5
  dplyr::filter(Status != 5) 

Patients Time Status
1:        2    a      4
2:        2    b      4

# one option to get all distinct patients 
df %>% 
  # exclude everything where Status is 5
  dplyr::filter(Status != 5) %>% 
  # unique values per column or column combination
  dplyr::distinct(Patients)

Patients
1:        2

# on option to get all data of patien with at least one status != 5
df %>% 
  # exclude everything where Status is 5
  dplyr::filter(Status != 5) %>% 
  # unique values per column or column combination
  dplyr::distinct(Patients) %>% 
  # join back on original data to get all values for specific patients
  dplyr::inner_join(df, by = "Patients")

Patients Time Status
1:        2    a      4
2:        2    b      4
3:        2    c      5
4:        2    d      5
5:        2    e      5
6:        2    f      5
```